# Como obtener un texto que esta dentro de unas comillas vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

```
wscript.exe //B "C:\Users\S4LSAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\virus.vbs"
```

Y Quero obtener la ruta dentro de las comillas, para que me quede esto :

```
C:\Users\S4LSAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\virus.vbs
```

No logro hacer esto en vb.net, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buen dia. Lamentablemente no nos brindas muchos detalles sobre como viene la variable que contiene toda la ruta que nos brindas, si fueras mas especifico te lo agradeceriamos. Por otro lado, te brindo esta solucion:

```
    Dim path As String = "wscript.exe //B 'C:\Users\S4LSAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\virus.vbs'"
    Dim i As Integer = path.IndexOf("'")
    Dim justpath As String = path.Substring(i + 1, path.IndexOf("'", i + 1) - i - 1)
```

Con esto facilmente extraes la cadena que esta entre las comillas simples. Te brindo esta solucion ya que no nos das mas detalles.  Saludos

Comment: Funciono gracias!